# Model multilevel proportion data

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, beta-regression, beta-distribution

Suppose that one has data on a proportion $P$ measured on a continuous scale.  Further suppose that this data has a grouped structure -- some proportions are clustered according to a certain variable $g$ (location, say).  Further say that you've got a covariate $X$ that your think is correlated with $P$.  You want to know the effect of $X$ on $P$ in order to get conditional distributions of $P$ given $X$.

One could simply run a linear model with random effects, but predictions may go beyond the 0,1 bounds, and intervals will be wrong.

One could fit a binomial(logit) GLM, but this may be a poor model for the data, as it would lead to overly upward (downward) skewed intervals near the boundaries, and a perhaps-artificial sigmoidal shape to the predictions.

Could a Beta regression work for this sort of problem?  If so, how would one incorporate the grouped structure of the data?  Any ideas for implementation in R?

Comment: This question seems to be *only* about whether this feature exists in R, & not about any of the related statistical issues. As such it is off-topic for CV (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help)). Your best option for answering this question would be to ask on one of the [r-help mailing lists](http://www.r-project.org/mail.html), possibly `r-sig-mixed-models`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about whether this feature exists in R.

Comment: Technically I suppose that you're right.  CV often provides better answers however, and more google-able answers (which would benefit posterity more), in the case that somebody is willing to share any home-grown code.

Comment: @ACD a suggestion from Chat is to reword the question more generally how to estimate beta regression with random effects and mention you are looking for a R implementation if possible. If so edited, this could get reopened.

Comment: See the `glmmADMB` package (off-CRAN) ...

Comment: does that do it?

Comment: @ACD why not check?